# HTML/CSS: Div in td nr. 2 is align vertically under a div in td 1

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I got a problem :S I'm trying to add a div and a table into two tds and align them vertically by css. This looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='vertical-align: text-top;'>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Some Randomness on some lines<br><br><br>until here.</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style='vertical-align: text-top;'>
      <div style='width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;'>
        Some Random text here also on a few lines...<br><br><br>until here.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, the div appears just on the level of the last row of the left table. Why is this like this? ..... I got this problem earlier with images, but i just solved it by resizing the image...

Thanks for help!

Flo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use "`vertical-align:top`"

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Some Randomness on some lines<br><br><br>until here.</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style='vertical-align: top;'>
      <div style='width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;'>
        Some Random text here also on a few lines...<br><br><br>until here.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks :) (have to wait 8 mins for correct answer ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from the question what you are trying to do, but if you want them aligned vertically, you can change your HTML to make this just one table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='vertical-align: text-top;'>
      Some Randomness on some lines<br><br><br>until here.</td>
    <td style='vertical-align: text-top;'>
      <div style='width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;'>
        Some Random text here also on a few lines...<br><br><br>until here.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Q5YGm/

Comment: Well, I already do this. Inside the first TD there's just another table. But it won't work also with your solution, if I add there a Table or a Div or something... I had to change `vertical-align: text-top;` into `vertical-align: top;`

Answer (score -1):

I'd set the width and height of the TD's using HTML, use the valign property on the TD's, and finally use the style property to style your TD's border using CSS.

```
<td height="300" width="300" valign="top" style="border: 1px solid red;">
   text here
</td>
```